# Who was the rightful owner of the Sword of Gryffindor?

Tags: harry-potter

**Who was the rightful owner of the Sword of Gryffindor?**

> ‘So where is it?’ Harry asked suspiciously.
>   ‘Unfortunately,’ said Scrimgeour, ‘that sword was not Dumbledore’s to give away. **The sword of Godric Gryffindor is an important historical artefact, and as such, belongs –**’
>   ‘It belongs to Harry!’ said Hermione hotly. ‘It chose him, he was the one who found it, it came to him out of the Sorting Hat –’
>   ‘According to reliable historical sources, the sword may present itself to any worthy Gryffindor,’ said Scrimgeour. ‘That does not make it the exclusive property of Mr Potter.’
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 109 - Bloomsbury - chapter seven - *The Will of Albus Dumbledore*</sub>

Scrimgeour doesn't go on to say the Sword of Gryffindor belongs to the Ministry, although he does say it does not belong to Harry. Even so, I'm sceptical enough of the Ministry's motives to conclude that a case could probably be made for Harry being the sword's rightful owner. But was he?

Is there a canon answer to this question? If not a direct answer from the books, a speculative answer in the spirit of canon is welcome.

**Who was the rightful owner of the Sword of Gryffindor?**

Comment: According to the Goblins, it's theirs. But I'm sure that's not what Scrimgeour was about to say.

Comment: I'm with Kevin. The sword was made by the Goblins, and as such falls under Goblin jurisdiction and their laws. And according to that, belongs to them. Unless there was a written contract between them and Godric stipulating otherwise, it was a lease, not a sale.

Comment: @Kevin - I hope you're happy now.

Comment: man, I really really really wanted to ask this for soooo long. just dunno what happens to my mind when I get on this site :P

Comment: @AwalGarg - Did the answers below satisfy your curiosity or are there other elements you'd have wanted me to address?

Comment: @Richard Yes, what _exactly_ was scrimgeour about to say when that stupid know-it-all interrupted the wise man?

Comment: @AwalGarg - My guess would be either; "belongs...with the Ministry" or "belongs...in the possession of Hogwarts".

Comment: @Richard Or maybe... "belongs to Awal Garg" :P...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15564/discussion-between-richard-and-awal-garg).

Comment: I did find this btw: J.K. Rowling: Griphook was wrong – Gryffindor did not ‘steal’ the sword, not unless you are a goblin fanatic and believe that all goblin-made objects really belong to the maker.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Western Law and the Right of Property

Without a copy of the wizard world's equivalent of the "[Commentaries on the Laws of England](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commentaries_on_the_Laws_of_England)", it's impossible to determine who the true owner of the sword would be. If, however we assume that the laws are broadly equivalent to English Common Law then the answer is actually pretty straightforward:

Blackstone's [commentary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_property_law) states that...

> "*...things personal...are goods, money, and **all other movables which
>   may attend the owner's person wherever he thinks proper to go***".

Since Godric Gryffindor was instrumental in creating the Sorting Hat for the exclusive use of Hogwarts and since he subsequently enchanted the Sword to appear within the hat in times of need, it follows that the sword can be treated as a [bequest of assets](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/bequest) to the School.

As Headmaster, it's highly unlikely that Dumbledore has the authority to dispose of a valuable asset belonging to the School without the express permission of the School's Board of Governors. This means that the most likely answer is that the sword is (and remains) **the property of Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry** in perpetuum until such time as it is disposed of in a lawful manner.

---

With regard to Scrimgeour's decision to take the sword into custody, it's highly likely that the Ministry of Magic has sufficient [legal authority](http://uk.practicallaw.com/uklegislation/ukpga/1948/5/section/4/enacted) to justify (temporarily) confiscating it in a time of national crisis. This wouldn't affect who the ultimate owner was and they could expect to have it returned once the crisis was at an end.

Comment: I don't think that Scrimgeour ever had the sword in his custody. At least he didn't when he came to give Harry, Ron, and Hermione the items left to them by Dumbledore. Thoughts?

Comment: No, it was still missing at that point and even if they could find it, there's no reason to assume it wouldn't simply turn up again in the Sorting Hat when required.

Comment: It wasn't missing at that point it was in Dumbledore's office (the real one behind the painting and the fake one on display, which Neville, Ginny and Luna try to steal later on)

Comment: I like this answer much more than your Goblin one, simply because JKR has stated that despite the Goblins' vehement beliefs system, they are, quite simply, wrong. The sword belonged to Gryffindor and he was free to pass it along to whomever he liked; I think it's clear he bequeathed it to Hogwarts. :)

Comment: I like the arguments in both your answers. But do you view them as (a) complementary (e.g. Gryffindor stole the sword, but if his ownership is taken as legitimate the sword belongs to Hogwarts), in which case they should probably be a single answer, or (b) contradictory (in which case one is correct, or neither is)? Either way, I’m not sure there should be two answers (except of course for the repz ;) )

Comment: @adamant - I posted both to show that the truth can be a two-edged sword. Personally I err on the side of the goblins.

Comment: @Valorum - Hmmm. Yeah. I have always felt that it is fine to present multiple possibiities in one answer. In particular, I think multiple answers by the same person have a lot of potential to confuse people as to which is the right answer.

Comment: @Adamant - In this instance, I really don't see how you could reconcile two diametrically opposed theses in *a single answer*.

Comment: @Valorum - Honestly,  it seems as if there is a right answer. I am not sure why one would need to post a wrong one too. If you actually felt that either legal analysis was equivalent, saying "It depends" and listing the possibilities would seem sufficient. And you *don't* seem to actually think they are equally  valid....

Comment: If the thesis is "wizards think he did not steal it,  goblins think he did,  goblin law should hold," that's one answer. Even if the thesis is "it is subjective which law holds" or "it does not matter," as you seem to be getting at,  a single answer still suffices.

Comment: Same kind of thing [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/139285/51379). One answer will end up being incorrect,  or at best the OP is remembering aspects of both and one would need to be incorporated into the other to be complete.

Comment: @Adamant - That's not how SE works. If you have multiple answers, you can (and should) press the answer button more than once.

Answer (score 31):

### Art Repatriation and Cultural Emperialism

Pottermore contains an account of the creation of the [**Goblin Sword of Ragnuk**](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Ragnuk), commonly (but erroneously) known as the "*Sword of Gryffindor*".

As you can see below, even though the (human) author has attempted to conceal the **true ownership** behind a skein of lies and mistruths, it should be immediately apparent that Godric Gryffindor used **illegal magic** and **threats of genocide** to prevent its true owner, the Goblin King Ragnuk from regaining possession of it, in full accordance with Goblin law.

> The sword was made to Godric Gryffindor's specifications by Ragnuk the
>   First, finest of the goblin silversmiths, and therefore King (in
>   goblin culture, the ruler does not work less than the others, but more
>   skilfully). When it was finished, Ragnuk coveted it so much that he
>   pretended that Gryffindor had stolen it from him, and sent minions to
>   steal it back. Gryffindor defended himself with his wand, but did not
>   kill his attackers. Instead he sent them back to their king bewitched,
>   to deliver the threat that if he ever tried to steal from Gryffindor
>   again, Gryffindor would unsheathe the sword against them all.
>
> The goblin king took the threat seriously and left Gryffindor in
>   possession of his rightful property, but remained resentful until he
>   died. This was the foundation for the false legend of Gryffindor's
>   theft that persists, in some sections of the goblin community, to this
>   day. - <sub><sup>[Pottermore](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/The_Sword_of_Gryffindor)</sup></sub>

One of the modern representatives of the noble Goblin race; a hero named [Griphook](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Griphook) attempted to convince a group of bigoted young human wizards of the true ownership of the Sword. Their first instinct was to deny this claim, then to make an attempt to cheat the Goblins out of their rightful inheritance;

> ‘No!’ cried the goblin, bristling with anger as he pointed a long
>   finger at Ron. ‘Wizarding arrogance again! **That sword was Ragnuk the
>   First’s, taken from him by Godric Gryffindor! It is a lost treasure, a
>   masterpiece of goblinwork! It belongs with the goblins!** <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sup></sub>

We later learn that Goblin law is extremely clear, all goblin-made objects are considered to be sold under lease and should return to the possession of the Goblin **maker** after the death of their lessor;

> ‘You don’t understand, Harry, nobody could understand unless they have
>   lived with goblins. **To a goblin, the rightful and true master of any
>   object is the maker, not the purchaser. All goblin-made objects are,
>   in goblin eyes, rightfully theirs.’**
>
> ‘But if it was bought –’
>
> ‘– then they would consider it rented by the one who had paid the
>   money. They have, however, great difficulty with the idea of
>   goblin-made objects passing from wizard to wizard. You saw Griphook’s
>   face when the tiara passed under his eyes. He disapproves. I believe
>   he thinks, as do the fiercest of his kind, that it ought to have been
>   returned to the goblins once the original purchaser died. **They
>   consider our habit of keeping goblin-made objects, passing them from
>   wizard to wizard without further payment, little more than theft.’** <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sup></sub>

---

The principle of the [repatriation of looted artworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_repatriation) and objects of cultural significance is well known and widely accepted across the civilised world. Many consider it undeniable that the Goblin Sword of Ragnuk is one of those items. As such, the sword is the lawful and righful possession of the Goblin people both **morally and legally**.

Comment: Not sure if you're roleplaying or just confused, but the first reference (from Pottermore) supports Godric's claim, clearly, rather than Ragnuk's.

Comment: @TylerH - It's clearly human propaganda. If you read it critically, you can see the tale of a man who stole a sword, then threatened to commit genocide to keep hold of it.

Comment: It's clearly not. This is not the appropriate site to roleplay a Harry Potter goblin supporter.

Comment: @tylerh - An uncritical reading shows a man who was perfectly willing to threaten genocide over the (disputed) possession of a sword. Although Ron dismisses the claim as "Goblin stories", Hermione immediately notes that wizard behaviour toward the goblin race had been consistently dreadful. No roleplay required.

Comment: You say "uncritical reading" as if it's a positive adjective.

Comment: @shadur - uncritical in the sense of not trying to apply excessive criticism or analysis to what's in front of you; e.g. a powerful man willing to kill for a possession.

Comment: Alternately, a powerful man realizing that the kind of people who send a hit squad out to reclaim a possession they believe they own is going to *keep* sending hit squads until they succeed, likely killing him in the process or at least forcing him to kill many of them, unless he convinces them that the attempt would cost them more than it's worth.

Comment: Also, what exactly is "excessive analysis" ? Any interpretation of the events that doesn't support the conclusion you clearly wanted to reach the moment you started reading?

Comment: @shadur - Excessive analysis would include trying to ascribe emotions to a participant, as you have done

Comment: I fail to see the human propaganda in the quoted text. You have a wizard who has drawn up specs for a sword. A craftsman creates the sword to those specifications, and the wizard takes possession of it. And that means that the sword is somehow owned by the craftsman (or craftsgoblin in this case) simply because he changed his mind about keeping it after the sword was delivered? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Ellesedil All joking aside, Ragnuk trying to take the sword back in Gryffindor's lifetime would not be legal even under Goblin Laws, but since according to HP, all Goblin craft is legally *leased* for the lifetime of the person who ordered the item and never sold for perpetual possession, once Godric was dead, by Goblin Law the possession would indeed revert to the Goblins. Wizard Law won't ever agree to this, however, because they understand the contract to be one of sale, and they're the ones in charge and the ones who suffer from amending their understanding of the contract.

Comment: The problem here becomes a matter of Venue; who's law applies?  That is normally stipulated in a contract or sale agreement, and I haven't seen anything supporting a 'Meeting of the Minds' during the negotiation which would indicate which governs -- Per Goblin law, it's the Goblin's after Gryffindor dies.  Per Human law, it belongs to whoever he passes title to.  Absent a signed / witnessed agreement, I think this is unanswerable -- the two laws are mutually exclusive on this matter, and if it didn't occur to anyone that this conflict existed at the time, it wouldn't have been spelled out.

Comment: See [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53466/looking-for-a-story-with-water-earth-fire-as-rock-paper-scissors) for something similar -- there was a meeting of the minds, but with different understanding of the terms.. No one was at fault, really, but both parties justifiably thought the other was.  The only solution seems a pragmatic one, not a legal one.

Comment: @KHW - The more I look into it, the more I side with the goblins on this one. Prior to Rome (I) in 2010, in a contract without a jurisdiction clause, the relevant court would be where "the majority of the actions of the agreement took place". That's undeniably the Goblin workshop.

Comment: @Richard -- Valid point, but applying RL Muggle law to it is slightly questionable.  Roman law since about the sixth century says 'Ei incumbit probatio qui dicit, non qui negat', yet the HP world seems to go by a more Napoleonic code, specifically the [Inquisitorial System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inquisitorial_system) -- Not that surprising, perhaps, since in many ways the Wizardling world seems to have stagnated in many ways with a more Medieval mindset.  Still, the BASIS of contract law is enshrining a 'Meeting of the Minds' into a concrete document -- and that's where things failed.

Comment: Oh my god I uncovered this in 2016 and it is the best thing ever.

Answer (score 3):

If a wand chooses its owner, it stands to reason that any other sufficiently sapient magical object may (and will) do the same. I'd hazard a guess that magical law has a clause somewhere regulating the rights of a lawful owner, in the case that the object under dispute chooses another owner in their place. Think of it as being like a custody case: if a child is old enough, the family court will usually take their preference under advisement when deciding custody.

The fact that the sword "wants" to go to Harry should, by all magical logic, be taken into account by the legal system. Magic obeys its own laws, and a magical object's compulsion to belong to a specific owner can withstand any law to the contrary.

Comment: The sword was enchanted by Godric Gryffindor but unlike the Sorting Hat, there's no reason to assume that the Goblin Sword of Ragnuk is sentient.

Comment: I like this theory -- it does make sense in that the Sword of Gryffindor does present itself to any worthy Gryffindor who is in need of its help. It is, it would seem, the sword choosing who is worthy of its use (as do wands), so what you say about the sword choosing its next owner could make sense. It seems convincing that Goblin law does not apply, especially as JKR has said as much (see Simon's comment above), so there must another way the sword claims its owner, for lack of a better way of putting it. +1 :)

Comment: +1. it's not the same weapon that was given to GG in the transaction we know almost nothing about. It was altered by GG / other users/ magic in Hogwarts. Among other things, it changes location according to certain conditions. Whether it is sentient (and in my opinion it is) or simply an enchanted weapon isnt that important. The sword of Ragnuk is no more therefore it can't be returned.

Comment: Enchanting an object seems to have the effect of giving it a bit of smarts (specifically, the smarts of whoever cast the enchantment). While the goblins may think that the sword belongs to Ragnuk's heir, the sword definitely has other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

### No-one, including Rowling herself, is actually sure.

The rights of property (as regards the Sword of Gryffindor/Sword of Ragnuk) appear to be ***mutually incompatible***, with [both sides](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60728/20774) presenting [cogent arguments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60738/20774).

> **JKR:** *I am interested in what happens when cultural beliefs collide. In the
> Harry Potter books, the most militant of the goblin race consider all
> goblin-made objects to be theirs by right, although a specific object
> might be made over to a wizard for his lifespan upon a payment of
> gold. Witches and wizards, like Muggles, believe that once payment has
> been made, the object belongs to them and their descendants or
> legatees in perpetuity.*
>
> ***This is a clash of values without a solution,
> because each side has a different concept of what is right.** It
> therefore presents Harry with a difficult moral dilemma when Griphook
> demands the sword as payment for his services in Deathly Hallows.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Hogwarts: An (in)Complete and (un)Reliable guide](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hogwarts:_An_Incomplete_and_Unreliable_Guide)</sup></sub>

Comment: If JKR were willing, this could be followed up with a short story in which Harry walks into Gringott's, asks if the Heir of Ragnuk is available to receive some property, and hand the sword over. "While I recognize your claim, I cannot promise that the sword will do likewise. It seems to have a mind of its own."

Answer (score 0):

The sword belonged to Godric Gryffindor because it is called the sword OF Godric Gryffindor.

However after Godric died he left it to the heir of Gryffindor. No one knew who the heir was so the Ministry of magic claimed it as their own

Comment: This is just a speculation. Besides, ministry didn't claim it as their own.

Comment: One of the key elements of attempting to repatriate a (supposedly) stolen item is to dispute its name. Hence why the Argentinians insist on calling the Falkland Islands the Malvinas and why the Greeks insist on calling the Elgin Marbles the Parthenon Marbles. Note that the Goblins refer to it as the Sword of Ragnuk

Comment: @Valorum Also why Indians call it the Kohinoor diamond whereas the Brits term it as a component part of the Crown Jewels. A lot of power indeed lies in a name.