# 1950s 'Space Patrol' episode

Tags: episode-identification, space-patrol

Commander Corey and Cadet Happy (did he ever advance beyond the rank of 'cadet'?) board an old, abandoned space station that is about to be destroyed as a menace to navigation. Criminals hiding out aboard the station (which I distinctly remember was a [von Braun-type wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_wheel_space_station)) capture them but the good guys save the day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is "***Prometheus Bound for Destruction***" (AKA "***The Phantom Spaceship***").

> Episode #40 "Prometheus Bound for Destruction" September 29, 1951
>
> Buzz, Tonga and Happy blast off to explore an obsolete space station
> called Prometheus, which is orbiting Ganymede, Jupiter's fourth moon.
> **Prometheus is scheduled for destruction by Space Safety.** Boarding the
> station, the **Space Patrollers are threatened by an old space criminal**
> who has hidden there for forty years and resists their efforts to
> remove him. Preoccupied, they fail to hear the broadcast warning all
> ships in the vicinity that hydrogen torpedoes will destroy the station
> within minutes.
>
> <sup><sub>[Space Patrol: Missions of Daring in the Name of Early Television](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Z74RN6CBnh0C&pg=PA389&lpg=PA389&dq=space%20patrol%20%22The%20Space%20Derelict%22&source=bl&ots=7yo5NM6wQP&sig=mjKxE0zxEk3xAKfX2PbT3JIcMlE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj2fWhgOzOAhWlDcAKHTneCRMQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=station&f=false)</sub></sup>

The station was a rotating-wheel.

Answer (score 2):

IMDB lists Season 2, Episode 29 of Space Patrol as ["The Derelict Space Station"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0706202/?ref_=ttep_ep29).

> Episode #82 "The Derelict Space Station" July 19, 1952
>
> ***Buzz, Happy and Tonga become involved in a harrowing adventure when
> two dangerous criminals overcome the trio in a spaceship which goes
> out of control and hurtles toward the planet Earth.***
>
> *Merrick: Peter Mamakos
>
> Klinger: Tom Daly*
>
> <sub><sup>[Space Patrol: Missions of Daring in the Name of Early Television](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CxIkCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA383&lpg=PA383&dq=space%20patrol%20%22The%20Derelict%20Space%20Station%22.&source=bl&ots=p5MzNmEjiJ&sig=0_Xrzy-4lj3qz2YQYYQchnHc1Kg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimv7PP-uvOAhVlK8AKHZkTABMQ6AEIQzAL#v=onepage&q=space%20patrol%20%22The%20Derelict%20Space%20Station%22.&f=false)</sup></sub>

Comment: The title sounds right, but (unless my memory is completely scrambled - it  has been 50 years) it is not the episode in question. I distinctly remember the space station was a von Braun-type wheel, rather than the ball type in this story.